# Making a <div> horizontally scrollable when its content doesn't fit the window

Tags: html, css

Good day! I have two `div`s: the `left` and the `content`. The `content` should overlap the `left` so I made the `content`'s position `absolute`. Now, when the `left`'s contents don't fit the window, there is no horizontal scrollbar of course because it is just overlapped (I need to overlap it for some reason). How can I make a horizontal scrollbar appear in the `left` `div`? Here is my `css`:

```
.left {
    width: 70%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.content {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    background-color: #2b3e50;
    border-left-width:5px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:#153450;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

And here is the `html`:

```
<div id="loader" class="left" style="border-right-width:15px;">

        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span14">
                        @content
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Please help me. Been stuck here for a while now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I could be completely wrong about this but I have not seen a div such as you describe. I can imagine making a responsive table and being able to scroll across more easily... Does it have to be a div?

Comment: Yes because the `div` that is being overlapped must retain its size or its contents mess up. So I think a `div` with an `absolute` position would do.

Comment: I don't know how to make a div as such. One suggestion I have is you can use a table and put contents in it http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables gives a great example of a responsive table (just download the code on the right and its good to go). Easy to download and seems to be something you may be looking for. I don't suggest using tables often in place of divs. It's bad programming but this may help for now.

Comment: Can you put this on JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use fixed widths, not %. Remove `width: 70%`and replace it with the width you want, say `300px`. Here's a fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/8A6R8/2/**